# Excel file is error after export from report viewer

Tags: asp.net, excel, openxml, reportviewer

I had created the report using report viewer in asp.net. But recently I found that it happen some error when I tried to open the excel(xlsx) file after i download. It came out with the error message
"We found a problem with some content in 'Reportest(34).xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

After I click Yes, it have another message box pop out which is said Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error.  Illegal xml character. Line 3, column 28935.

[image]

I had tried to zip it and already find out the reason why it is error. I found that the error is because of the unreadable character in the line 28935

[image]

How do I handle this error using the error. Is that my excel version? Because previously it is working fine. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Best Regards,
Choo

Comment: Well, which versions of Excel are involved? It's also not clear which character is "unreadable"? Are you sure this character was part of workbooks which did open without an error?

Comment: What code are you using to trigger the file download?

Comment: @Cindy Meister I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and the type of file is Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx). I was involve ' <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>' into top of aspx page. The unreadable character is char(31) which is "US" word show in the picture 2.

Comment: @petelids I am using vb.net to write the code and just unzipped the xlsx file to trigger the error.

Comment: You'd probably need to ask in a specialized *end-user* group for Excel about whether/how versions support non-printing ANSI characters (31 is listed as a "unit separator"). Googling confirms that Excel can have problems with such characters and the recommendation is to replace with standard characters. The question presents itself as to *why* the ReportViewer would be exporting non-printing characters in its content. Perhaps what you should be asking is how to suppress the ReportViewer from doing this, or how to substitute a valid character into the "stream" that's generating the report.

Answer (score 1):

I already get the solution. I added additional xls format (excel 2003) in report viewer to download and the problem is solved. The report open properly. Thanks!